# java.exe -version and pushd?

Tags: command-line, java

I have noticed that when I run the following command

```
Pushd \\RemoteMachine\C$ && java.exe -version
```

I get the java version of the computer I am on. However when I run the pushd command with a search option like the command below I get the actual information found on that computer.

```
Pushd \\RemoteMachine\C$ && dir /s java.exe
```

Why is this the case? Is it possible to run java.exe -version on a remote PC and have it output that computers information on my screen?

Comment: What Pushd are you using? The built-in Pushd command just pushes a file path onto a stack for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `java.exe` in your example, the shell only searches the current directory (i.e. `\\RemoteMachine\C$`) but *not* its subdirectories. (In other words, it's more like `dir java.exe` without the `/s`.)

Since there is no such file in the remote machine's `C:\`, the next step is to search the directories specified in your `%PATH%` environment variable (which normally only contains local directories).

To solve your problem, specify the full path to `java.exe`. You don't even need to use `pushd`:

```
C:\> "\\RemoteMachine\C$\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -version
```

Answer (score 2):

[PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) by SysInternals does exactly what you need it to. Your example would be:

```
psexec \\RemoteMachine java.exe -version
```

Comment: I cant use outside programs like PsExec or that would be perfect. I figured out a way around it but cant supply my own answer yet. After I pushd I need to cd \location of java.exe\. Then I can run -version and it displays correctly

Answer (score 1):

Although PsExec would get the job done I am unable to use that.

I am able to perform the command `java.exe -version` on the remote machine by changing the directory once I used `pushd`.

```
Pushd \\RemoteComputer\C$
cd "Program Files\Java\jre6\bin"
Java.exe -version
```

Or all at once

```
Pushd \\RemoteComputer\C$ && cd "Program Files\Java\jre6\bin" && java.exe -version && popd
```