# Passing Log in Credentials with Pushd? other command?

Tags: command-line

My Scenario: I am running the `pushd` command to run searches on remote domain computers. However the search performs very slow/or not at all when a user is not logged on to the machine(machine is still powered on.)

I was wondering if it is possible to pass log in credentials with the `pushd` command. If not what are some alternate choices?

I cannot use other software or packages such as PsExec.

Comment: For those who read this and think it to be nonsense (the `pushd` command having no search mechanism and having nothing to do with searching), I recommend reading [`harper89`'s other question](http://superuser.com/questions/296452/) for context.  `harper89`, write precisely what you are actually doing in questions, not some confused outline that people won't understand.

Comment: I am searching remote computers once I use pushd to "connect" to them.

Comment: I think he's using it to connect to remote systems and checking versions of installed executables, such as java.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, I still wonder why PsExec is not available when alternate choices are being asked for-- it's a Microsoft utility, with the only difference between it and `pushd` being that it's not shipped by default...

Comment: these commands are being worked into an application and PsExec would involve another possible download for the end user or machines that will be running the application.

Comment: @harper89: FWIW, SysInternals make their tools available over WebDAV, so you can just `copy /y \\live.sysinternals.com\psexec.exe "%TEMP%\psexec.exe"`. On the other hand, I would *not* recommend putting this into a distributable script, because of a misconfiguration at their "live" server. (Windows normally tries SMB before WebDAV, and the SysInternals server quietly drops SMB and ICMP, therefore a **long** timeout delay is caused during each connection.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use:

```
net use \\RemoteComputer\c$ password /user:MY_DOMAIN\remoteUsername
"\\RemoteComputer\c$\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -version"
net use \\RemoteComputer\c$ /d
```

(Edited to add simplifications from grawity from comments. Learn something new every day!)

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to specify a drive letter for `net use` -- just passing path/user will cause Windows to connect and authenticate. Although `pushd` will create a drive letter *anyway* -- but it's not always needed; most programs will accept `\\remotecomputer\C$` just fine.

Comment: @grawity: You mean `net use \\computer <credentials>` and then `\\computer\path\executable -arg` will work as expected?

Comment: Yes, that's right. (To disconnect, `net use \\computer\IPC$ /d`.)

Comment: One correction to your edits: If you specify a share name when connecting, you must specify the same when disconnecting too. It's only bare `\\computer` (as in your comment) that gets translated to `\\computer\IPC$`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this command to map a drive. This guarantees that connection will persists and you have a drive name mapped to E: so you can just call that drive name to run commands.

```
Net Use  E: \\server\share my_password /user:username  /persistent:MY_DOMAIN/username /y
```