# Password too long for Windows Credential Manager to store?

Tags: windows, nas

I'm trying to set windows to remember the credential of a network drive. However everytime it used the wrong credentials. After some inspection in the credential manager it happears that the password saved is only 8 characters long, while the original password is 55 characters long (I know, it's long, but I don't think it is that excessive).

Even manually inserting the credentials doesn't seem to work the password is always stored as 8 chars, so is my password too long for windows to handle?

**EDIT :** If you want to know how I know that it is 8 chars long: when I edit the entry in the credential manager it shows 8 dots as password. However I've actually noticed that it shows 8 dots for every stored password, even the ones that work, so I guess it's some kind of prection from windows.

However, when I turn my computer on it tells me that the credentials for the network unit are wrong and it prompts new credentials. In the box there are 14 dots in the password box, but I don't know if that is also supposed to be some sort of "placeholder" text

Comment: When I edit the entry in the credential manager it shows 8 dots as password. However I've actually noticed that it shows 8 dots for every stored password, even the ones that work, so I guess it's some kind of prection from windows.

Comment: That is correct. Most password managers won't show you the length of the stored password. Some do however offer the option to show the clear text password in which case the whole password would be displayed. The Windows credential manager doesn't have that option. What actually happens if you try to access the drive after storing the password in the manager?

Comment: When I boot up it asks for the credentials: I insert the correct password and I can access the drive, but when I reboot it will ask me again

Comment: Did you try to use a shorter password? What does the other side use to provide the share? There might be indeed limits on the length that you can't see. For alternatives maybe have a look at [Windows refuses to remember network share credentials](https://superuser.com/questions/309570/windows-refuses-to-remember-network-share-credentials).

Comment: @Seth I have no idea what the provider use, I only know that is is a Linux webserver nothing more. But considering that once I enter the credential I can access it just fine, I'd say that the problem is client-side.

Comment: Did you read the answer to the question I linked? Did any of that help? What kind of share is it? Up until now I assumed a standard Windows/CIFS share but if you're talking about a Linux webserver it might be a WebDAV?