# Win 10 ver2004 deletes SMB access after going through cold start

Tags: windows, windows-10, samba, windows-server

I have been encountering sporadic issues with SMB username/password being deleted on the client station. Started with build 19041, and seems to be related only to the client, as it happened for an SMB being hosted on 10 Pro and WinServ 2019.

Happened on cold boots only so far, and on one stations the SMB username was the same as local account name. No info on Microsoft Forums, or support articles for this particular issue. Best I found was: https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/3181029/smb-file-server-share-access-is-unsuccessful-through-dns-cname-alias
But the whole thing is not set up as SMB v1, so shouldn't even apply.

Strange part is, if you check credentials manager, you can see they are there, saved, and with correct path, but when user tries to acess the SMB, they get prompted for username and pass.

Has anyone encoutered the same problem with the current build, or better, found solution to it?

Comment: Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/616188/8672).

Comment: That looks exactly like my problem. Thanks, will try next time it pops up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows refuses to remember network share credentials](https://superuser.com/questions/309570/windows-refuses-to-remember-network-share-credentials)